# What does symbolic link lock -> /run/lock/?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

I am looking at my var directory.
what does a symbolic link really serve for?

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        9 апр  8 07:47 lock -> /run/lock/
```

Links lock to /run/lock/?

Comment: Are you asking about the purpose of symbolic links in general or about why /var/lock is linked specifically? (I mean, there's nothing special about this link, it just does what any other link does.)

Comment: @u1686_grawity about va/lock specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very thorough discussion of the subject is found in the post
[What are "/run/lock" and "/run/shm" used for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169495/what-are-run-lock-and-run-shm-used-for).

The following is a quoted of the excellent
[answer of user ish](https://askubuntu.com/a/169526/963426).

> > Short answer: they store temporary system files, including device locks and memory segments shared between different processes. Don't
> > worry, they usually use a *fraction* of their "size" shown by `df`
>
> 1. **`/run` is, in general, a temporary filesystem (tmpfs) residing in RAM** (aka "ramdisk"); its meant for storing "temporary" system or
>    state files which may be critical but *do not* require persistence
>    across reboots.
>
> - `/run` is actually a fairly new innovation, and was added a couple of years ago to replace the multiple tmpfs's that used to be created
>   (including `/var/lock` and `/dev/shm`) with a single unified root
>   tmpfs.
> - The main locations `/run` [replaces are:](http://wiki.debian.org/ReleaseGoals/RunDirectory)
>
> ```
>  /var/run → /run /var/lock → /run/lock /dev/shm → /run/shm
> [currently only Debian plans to do this] /tmp → /run/tmp [optional;
> currently only Debian plans to offer this]
> ```
>
> 2. **`/run/lock`** (formerly `/var/lock`) [contains lock files](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARLOCKLOCKFILES),
>    i.e. files indicating that a shared device or other system resource is
>    in use and containing the identity of the process (PID) using it; this
>    allows other processes to properly coordinate access to the shared
>    device.
> 3. **`/run/shm`** (formerly `/dev/shm`) is temporary world-writable shared-memory. [Strictly
>    speaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory#Specific_implementations),
>    it is intended as storage for programs using the POSIX Shared Memory
>    API. It facilitates what is known as *inter-process communication*
>    [(IPC)](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html), where different
>    processes can share and communicate via a common memory area, which in
>    this case is usually a normal file that is stored on a "ramdisk". Of
>    course, it can be and has been used in other creative ways as well ;)
> 4. **Do not be alarmed about the size**: importantly, many people running `df -h` and knowing that `/run` is backed by RAM are shocked
>    that their precious memory is being "wasted" by these mysterious
>    folders. Just like the *Linux ate my RAM myth* though, this belief is
>    incorrect.
>
> - The size shown is only the *maximum* that may be used
> - It defaults to 50% of physical RAM
> - Only as much shown in the *Used* column is actually in use, which in the above screenshot is less than 1 megabyte total
> - You can use the `ipcs -m` command to verify that the actual shared memory segments used match up to the `df` summary, and also see which
>   PIDs are using them
> - Like your regular RAM, `/run` is also eventually backstopped by your swap, so if you are using `/run/shm` for "faster" compile times, keep
>   that in mind ;)